# PHP datetime string differentiation

Tags: php, datetime

I can make a date object from string in both cases as below:

```
$dt = strtotime("2013-04-19 17:00:00");
//or
$dt = strtotime("10 hours");
```

I need a way so that I can differentiate between these two date type, whether it was relative or an absolute data string.

Any possible solution or clue please? Thanks.

Comment: I bit confused with the question but if you are looking into a way to know when it's relative or not, you could use some regex

Comment: to differentiate between two different input values you need to use regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use strtotime with different second parameters.

```
if(strtotime($val) == strtotime($val, 0)){
   //date is absolute
} else {
   // date is relative
}
```

`2013-04-19 17:00:00` will always be `2013-04-19 17:00:00` regardless of when the start time is.

the result of `10 hours` will be different depending on what the value of now is

Comment: Hi, just another additional question. If I use strtotime("16:00:00",0) it results 1970's 16:00:00, natually, "16:00:00" should mean an absoute time, today's time, right? Do you have any suggestion to recover from this? Thanks.

Comment: 0 as the second parameter is the unix epoch (12:00 Dec 31 1969) if you want the date relative to today then just omit the last parameter. `strtotime("16:00:00");

Comment: well for your given solution, I guess I need to use both ways and compare them right? What I meant, if the $val is "16:00:00", then the above comparison results in 'relative' condition block. But for such time, I would like it to be absolute time block, but sure it will work for "10 hours" as before. Please let me know if I could explain or I can show you an example as well if you haven't understood the issue yet.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly clear what you want, but if the `strtotime()` function doesn't help a simple regex could work:

```
$regex = "/^\d{1,2} hours$/";

$type = (preg_match($dt, $regex) ? "relative" : "absolute");
```

Just made it off the top of my head, it could be refined a lot better (`(hours|minutes|seconds)` or something).

It's also worth noting that this sort of customization is typical of a bad design.  `strtotime()` sounds like the right answer.

Comment: I was under the impression @Rana was looking for a way to know if the initial string *was* absolute or relative *after* `strtotime()` was used... (which is probably not possible)

Comment: Thanks steve for the clue. However finally I used regex to match date instead of the time like "/(\d{2,4})-(\D*)-(\d{2})/" and seems it is working.