# Relative Time Vs Absolute Time In PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Please check the following examples:

```
$date1 = strtotime("tomorrow 4:00 PM");
$date2 = strtotime("16:00:00");
$date3 = strtotime("10 hours");
$date4 = strtotime("+1 day");

echo date("Y m d H:i:s",$date1)."<br>";
echo date("Y m d H:i:s",$date2)."<br>";
echo date("Y m d H:i:s",$date3)."<br>";
echo date("Y m d H:i:s",$date4)."<br>";
```

It gives me the output as below:

```
2013 06 10 16:00:00
2013 06 09 16:00:00
2013 06 09 20:50:25
2013 06 10 10:50:25
```

I am considering first two example($date1 and $date2) as absolute data and the last two as relative date. Now, with only given the $date1/$date2/$date3/$date4 variables, is it possible to say whether it is relative time or an absolute time please?

I did get a solution on another thread: [PHP datetime string differentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890295/php-datetime-string-differentiation/16890384?noredirect=1#comment24525308_16890384) 
But that worked until I considered the 2nd example($date2 as an absolute value), where it doesn't work. Also, may suggested for regular expression checks, but that doesn't seem reliable either.

I was just wondering if php had some integrated way to tell this either from its functions or DateTime objects. I searched for, but didn't found anything.

Looking forward to listen for your suggestions/feedbacks/possible solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way, AFAIK but there is a trick that you can use with the second parameter to the `strtotime` function.

```
function is_absolute_time($time_string) {
  $time_shift = time() + 60; // 1 min from now

  $time_normal = strtotime($time_string);
  $time_shifted = strtotime($time_string, $time_shift);

  return $time_normal == $time_shifted;
}
```

The rationale is simple: If the time is absolute, a 1 min difference won't change the calculation by `strtotime` and both `$time_normal` and `$time_shifted` will be same. For relative times, however, the difference will be one minute (the value in `$time_shift` variable).

There is a caveat with this code though. This function will return `FALSE` even for absolute times (but not absolute dates) less than 1 minute from midnight. You can minimize this by changing `$time_shift` to:

```
$time_shift = time() + 5; // 5 seconds from now.
```

This code will now work properly until 5 seconds from midnight. I think you can go safely to as low as 2. There is an edge case that 1 second in future might not work.

To fix this problem altogether, you can try a different approach:

```
function is_absolute_time($time_string) {
  $epoch = 0; // Epoch
  $time_shift = 60; // 1 min from epoch

  $time_normal = strtotime($time_string, $epoch);
  $time_shifted = strtotime($time_string, $time_shift);

  return $time_normal == $time_shifted;
}
```

You can try this last solution directly. I am just building up the reason for the solution throughout this post.

Comment: @Rana this should be the answer, i'm going to delete mine since they are so similar that most people won't see the benefit of using this one over mine.

Comment: @Orangepill , yes it is the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given only the value `2013 06 10 16:00:00` the answer is simple: it's absolute. Whether this absolute timestamp was created as "absolute" timestamp or based on relation to another date is impossible to tell. All you have is "2013 06 10 16:00:00", there's no "residual relativeness" or anything of that kind still in it.

<sub>Even this is *relative* to the supposed birth of Christ though, which is relative to the earth floating around in space since the Big Bang... *trollface*</sub>